# Does the output "Stack overflow. Repeat 24047 times ..." mean that I found a bug in dotnet?

Tags: c#, .net, stack-overflow, clr

I wrote new code for my project and when I run my unit tests, I noticed that dotnet crashes.

But I did not know why. So I moved some of the code to a console application and run that. Then I got this output:

```
Stack overflow.
Repeat 24047 times:
--------------------------------
   at [[ class and method names here ]]
--------------------------------
   at [[ class and method names here ]]
```

After some time, there is a StackOverflowException: `The runtime refused to evaluate the expression at this time.` Afterwards, dotnet crashes again.

That's it. So the build process (compiling) is successful, but it seems that the CLR crashes??

Is this my fault or is this a bug in DotNet?

Edit: Here is some code and also the explanation for my problem. It was a recursion mistake on my site: https://dotnetfiddle.net/RD69Mk

Comment: Can you show us the code that crashes?

Comment: Stack overflow usually means that you have recursion somewhere in your code. Something like that: public void Foo() { Foo(); }

Comment: The bug is yours. You should read up on the phenomenon after which this web site is named: [stack overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow)

Comment: Tbh: I did not expect my OS to tell me that dotnet crashed. I expected dotnet to throw that exception and "end then". I have also never seen the output I showed with "Repeat XXXXX times" of dotnet. So I was unsure whether it's my fault or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's your fault. You have a recursive method call and you should have a look into the mentioned class and methods that are listed. Do not report to Microsoft.

Instead, use a debugger and step through your code to see what it does and why it does that.

The simplest program to reproduce the problem is

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Main();
    }
}
```

Is it a valid C# program? Yes. Does it make sense? No. Is it Microsoft's problem? No.

A recursive implementation needs a stopping condition, i.e. a case where it breaks out of the repeating call to itself.

Comment: I hate that you wrote the *simplest* and not the *shortest* because I was being an ass and wanted to comment that `Main() => Main();` is shorter and you ruined it. ;)

Comment: While this plausible and probable, I do not see where you get the certainty with which you diagnose a recursive call, a method call to be precise. I miss sufficient information in the question on this. Seeing that I also am surprised by the general tone of your post.

Comment: @Yunnosch it is a reasonable assumption from the symptoms. Is it theoretically possible that this is a Roslyn/JIT/etc bug: yes, but it is in the 0.01% range of possibilities, so without a "here's the runnable code that clearly isn't recursive" repro, honestly: I'm happy to make the same call. As for tone: it is frank, concise and unambiguous. I wouldn't say it is rude per-se. Could we dance around the fact that it is 99.99% OP's code being recursive, using flowery language to avoid offence? Sure. But it wouldn't change anything except take more time to read, and be less clear.

Comment: Ok, I found the reason. Thanks for the answers. It was indeed a recursion, but I did not expect it. It has to do with the params keyword and method overloading: https://dotnetfiddle.net/RD69Mk

Comment: @Yunnosch: usually I would not post things like "it's your fault". But I am trying to match OP's words and language choice which was "Is this my fault" and "should report to Microsoft"

Comment: Hi, thanks everybody for taking my concern serious. I see now that the diagnose was right (see comment by OP). But that is unimportant. More importantly I want to admit that I was imagining higher chances for other explanations and I additionally explicitly admit doing so for a language I have next to no knowledge in. My respect for those who know better, were right in their diagnose and (matching OPs phrasing, which I noticed by the way and seeing a much much higher probability than I did) were not actually rude. I did not flag by the way. I think a single "probably" would have had me silent.